# What is wrong with my kendo template

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-template

I need to display trailing `.00` decimals if the column `Value` of the provided model doesn't have it already.

What I have tried out is:

`template:AmountRepLookup == 1601 ?
"# if(#'#=Value#'#.indexOf('.') == -1) ){# #= '$' + Value # #}else{# #= '$' + Value +'.00' # #}#" :
"# if(#'#=Value#'#.indexOf('.') == -1) ){# #= Value + '%' # #}else{# #= Value +'.00%' # #}#"`

**Expected output:**

`$XX.00 or XX.00%`

Comment: try to use format #= kendo.format('{0:c2}', value)#

Comment: @VinaySingh the issue is I may get a percentage value as well. I have placed two conditions actually to achieve this. Updating the question

Comment: what needs to be done in that case

Comment: I have updated the question, I need to place a percent symbol at the end instead of dollar. Trying to achieve this using template

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use this

```
use {0:c2} for $ with 2 digit decimal
use {0:p} for percentage values

#= kendo.format('{0:c2}', value)# //dollar    
#= kendo.format('{0:p}', value)# //Percentage
```

You already have a Boolean conditions, just use formatting functions

Comment: can you confirm whether the javascript if part I have added in the template is correct/will it work?

Comment: it looks like, cant confirm without debugging, check and tell me. :)

Comment: Solution is building.. will tryout and accept answer

Comment: I am seeing the numbers without any kind of format while I try your solution